# By making the substitution $t=e^x$ and setting $z(t)=y(x)$, rewrite the following differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

By making the substitution $t=e^x$ and setting $z(t)=y(x)$, rewrite the following differential equation

$y''-y'+e^{2x}y = xe^{2x}-1$,    (1)

as one in terms of z and t. Hence find all solutions of (1).

I know I should be using the chain rule but I can't work out how to do it. Could someone please explain how to rewrite the equation?

Comment: $dy/dx=(dz/dt)(dt/dx)=t(dz/dt)$, $e^{2x}=t^2$ might get you started.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{dt} \frac{dt}{dx}$$

where

$$\frac{dt}{dx} = \frac{1}{dx/dt} = \frac{1}{1/t} = t$$

so that

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = t \frac{dy}{dt}$$

$$\frac{d^2 y}{dx^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{dy}{dx} = t \frac{d}{dt} \left (t \frac{dy}{dt} \right ) = t^2 \frac{d^2 y}{dt^2} + t \frac{dy}{dt}$$

Therefore, the equation becomes, using the substitution prescribed:

$$ t^2 \frac{d^2 z}{dt^2} + t^2 z = t^2 \log{t} - 1$$

or

$$z''+z=\log{t}-\frac{1}{t^2}$$

Not to give away the works, but it would seem from inspection that one solution is $z(t)=\log{t}$.